# Mapping combination of 4 integers to a single value

Tags: c++, hash, containers

I have 4 separate integers that need to be mapped to an arbitrary, constant value.

For example, 4,2,1,1 will map to the number 42

And the number 4,2,1,2 will map to the number 86.

Is there anyway I can achieve this by using #define's or some sort of std::map. The concept seems very simple but for some reason I can't think of a good, efficient method of doing it. The methods I have tried are not working so I'm looking for some guidence on implementation of this.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? For example, what do the 4 integers represent, and how is the number that they map to chosen? What will the map be used for?

Comment: In what range do the 4 integers lie? 0..2^31-1?

Comment: How many mappings do you expect to have? What is the maximum value each of these 4 integers might have?  How performance sensitive is the lookup - is it in the critical path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will a simple function suffice?

```
int get_magic_number( int a, int b , int c, int d)
{
   if( (a==4)&&(b==2)&&(c==1)&&(d==1) ) return 42;
   if( (a==4)&&(b==2)&&(c==1)&&(d==2) ) return 86;
   ...
   throw SomeKindOfError();
}
```

Now that may look ugly, but you can easily create a macro to pretty it up. (Or a helper class or whatever... I'll just show the macro as I think its easy.

```
int get_magic_number( int a, int b , int c, int d)
{
   #DEFINE MAGIC(A,B,C,D,X) if((a==(A))&&(b==(B))&&(c==(C))&&(d==(D))) return (X);
   MAGIC(4,2,1,1,  42);
   MAGIC(4,2,1,2,  86);
   ...
   #UNDEF MAGIC
   throw SomeKindOfError();
}
```

If you really care you can probably craft a constexpr version of this too, which you'll never be able to do with `std::map` based solutions.

Comment: This does look like a good option. Do you think all the if statements will be better/worse than the vector/map implementation @Yuushi mentioned in terms of performance?

Comment: It will depend on your compiler options/capabilities. (And maybe the order of the statements.) If you wanted to use the explicit version you can merge if branches together and use `else if` etc to get something that should/may be much faster than the map version. (Map has a lot of pointer traversal overhead etc.)

Comment: I expect in some cases (if a,b,c,d are constant) and get_magic_number is inline, then the function call may get removed entirely and replaced with its value. (But you'd need to look at the generated assembly to be sure).

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a `std::map<std::vector<int>, int>`, so that the `vector` containing `{4,2,1,1}` will have the value 42, and so on.

Edit: I agree `std::tuple` would be a better way to go if you have a compiler with C++11 support. I used a `std::vector` because it is arguably more portable at this stage. You could also use a `std::array<int, 4>`.

Comment: I am going to guess you have not actually tried this.  (Is std::vector LessThanComparable?)

Comment: If you know there's always 4 integers I think `array<int,4>` or tuple<int, int, int, int> should be used instead of `vector`.

Comment: @Nemo So define a compare(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) function and initialize the map with it...

Comment: @Nemo `operator<` (and therefore `std::less`) is defined for `std::vector`. The Standard requires it.

Comment: Yeah I used std::vector because it is more portable, and it is working nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to `boost::tuple`, `std::tuple` or `std::array`, you can implement a type holding 4 integers with a suitable less-than comparison satisfying [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html):

```
struct FourInts {
  int a,b,c,d;
  FourInts() : a(), b(), c(), d() {}
  bool operator<(const FourInts& rhs) const {
    // implement less-than comparison here
  }
};
```

then use an [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
std::map<FourInts, int> m;
```

If you organise your ints in an array of standard library container, you can use [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) for the less-than comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's always 4 integers mapped to 1 integer I suggest you go with:

```
std::map< boost::tuple<int, int, int, int>, int >
```

Comparison (lexicographical) is already defined for tuples.

Comment: unfortunately I don't want to link to the boost library just for a boost:tuple, I was looking for something a little simpler